# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to http://192.168.0.101:5602/api/status fails: fail to execute.

1. I am elasticsearch AND kibana running on a Windows 10 System
2. I am using Winlogbeat to fowards windows events from base machine to Elastic and Kibana - Its working
3. I am trying to forwards Logs from Win7 Guest (Vmware) to base machine hosted Kibana and elastic-  it throwing above mention error.
4. Elastic on port 9200 and kibana 5602.
5. i allowed incoming connection on both port at base machine and outgoing connection on both port on vm

Comment: Run a NMAP scan on ports 9200 and 5602. What does it say?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas 5602/tcp filtered a1-msc, 9200/tcp filtered wap-wsp

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I am able to telnet both the port

Comment: Can you get the request on the 192.168.0.101 computer directly by using localhost:5602/api/status ?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas yes able to access on 192.168.0.101 but not from vm, tried with multiple windows vm

Comment: is the computer 192.168.0.101 manually set or DHCP? If manual set to DHCP - what is the address now?